# If and while statements not working

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-ide, arduino-nano, arduino-due

The second and third `while` and `if` are not working but the first `while` and `if` do work. Am I doing something wrong?

```cpp
#include <DFMiniMp3.h> 

int sw1 = 3;
int sw2 = 4;
int sw3 = 5;

class Mp3Notify
{
  public:
    static void OnError(uint16_t errorCode)
    {
      // see DfMp3_Error for code meaning
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Com Error ");
      Serial.println(errorCode);
    }

    static void OnPlayFinished(uint16_t globalTrack)
    {
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Play finished for #");
      Serial.println(globalTrack);
    }

    static void OnCardOnline(uint16_t code)
    {
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Card online ");
      Serial.println(code);
    }

    static void OnCardInserted(uint16_t code)
    {
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Card inserted ");
      Serial.println(code);
    }

    static void OnCardRemoved(uint16_t code)
    {
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Card removed ");
      Serial.println(code);
    }
};
DFMiniMp3<HardwareSerial, Mp3Notify> mp3(Serial); //Create the UART connection to the module

void setup()
{

  //3 push buttons with pullups
  pinMode(sw1, INPUT); //Define each button as input with pullup
  pinMode(sw2, INPUT);
  pinMode(sw3, INPUT);

  digitalWrite (sw1, HIGH); //12 Votls supply set to off state
  digitalWrite (sw2, HIGH); //5 Votls supply set to off state
  digitalWrite (sw3, HIGH); //3 Votls supply set to off state

  Serial.begin(9600);
  mp3.begin(); //Start communication with the DFplayer module
  uint16_t volume = mp3.getVolume(); //Get actual volume
  mp3.setVolume(30); //Set new volum (max is 30)
  uint16_t count = mp3.getTotalTrackCount(); //Get the total tracks on the SD card in case we want to sue this later...
}

//just a fucntion that we use to create delays in "ms"
//without using the delay() function
void waitMilliseconds(uint16_t msWait)
{
  uint32_t start = millis();

  while ((millis() - start) < msWait)
  {
    // calling mp3.loop() periodically allows for notifications
    // to be handled without interrupts
    mp3.loop();
    delay(1);
  }
}

void loop()
{

  if (digitalRead(sw1) == LOW)
  {
    mp3.playMp3FolderTrack(1); // Play audio track 0001
    waitMilliseconds(5000); // 1s of delay
    while (digitalRead(sw1) == HIGH); // do nothing until state changes

  }

  if (digitalRead(sw2) == LOW)
  {
    mp3.playMp3FolderTrack(2); // Play audio track 0002
    waitMilliseconds(5000); // 1s of delay

    while (digitalRead(sw2) == HIGH); // do nothing until state changes

  }

  if (digitalRead(sw3) == LOW)
  {
    mp3.playMp3FolderTrack(3); // Play audio track 0002
    waitMilliseconds(5000); // 1s of delay

    while (digitalRead(sw3) == HIGH); // do nothing until state changes
  }
}
```

Comment: *Am I doing something wrong?* - if the alternative is that while/if statements do not work, then sure, you're doing something wrong. Please format your code properly and someone will help you find the mistake.

Comment: @SimSon, from the basic concept it looks fine. I need someone to help me with this.

Comment: Thanks for formating the code. The code just behaves differently than you expect, but those statements definitely work. What makes you believe they don't? Please add your observations and expectations into the question.

Comment: @SimSon, After "void loop" I have 3 "if" statements. The first one works, but not the second and not the third. If I changed the order of "if" statements then just the first work works. it doesn't matter which one of "if" statements are placed after first "if" statement but the after the first statement others doesn't work.

Comment: After pressing sw1, the while (digitalRead(sw1) == HIGH); line just makes it sits there without continuing with the rest of the code until you press sw1 again.

Comment: You should substitute the mp3 stuff with serial prints in each if clause and while loop to debug this.

Comment: @ocrdu, yes that is fine. but the second "if" statement doesn't function.

Comment: @ocrdu actually no. After execution enters any of the if statements, the while loop is meaningless if the button state hasn't changed

Comment: @Sim-Son They are push buttons that change state on release, and there's a delay that gives plenty of time for that release.

Comment: Does sw2 work if you haven't pushed sw1 at all since the last reset?

Comment: Maybe you better have a look how to read a button properly. The loop is executed so fast that reading a button like that won't give any good results anyway. You want to detect when the button changes its state, not if it is in a certain state. You're also better off using non-blocking code and avoiding delays like in the BlinkWithoutDelay example. If you keep several buttons pressed and release them randomly, you'll see that the 2. and 3. ifs are executes as well.

Comment: @ocrdu, no. Sw2 and sw3 don't work. If I change the order to sw2, sw3, sw3. Now the sw2 works. If I change the order to sw3, sw2, sw1 then sw3 works. I keep pressing all the buttons, but only the first "if" statement works and not others.

Comment: @ocrdu yes, you're right. Actually, after the while loop 1 has finished, the corresponding if statement is re-entered immediately on the next loop iteration unless button 2 or 3 is pressed.

Comment: Don't keep pressing all the buttons, reset the Arduino and only press sw2. Does sw2 work then?

Comment: @ocrdu, no, not working. Just the first if statement works.

Comment: How do you know if you only pressed sw2 after reset? Comment out the delays and the while loops. Do all buttons work then?

Comment: @ocrdu, 1- Power supply is off. 2- now power supply turned on. 3- non of switches connected. 3- switch number one held down. 4- MP3 played. 5- sw1 released. 6- sw2 pressed. 6- nothing happens. 

7- sw1 pressed and released to see if it needs reset. 
8- sw2 pressed, released, held down > nothing happens. 

10- if the the sw2 code moved above sw1 "if" statement then sw2 works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pressing `sw1`, the first `if` works. After releasing `sw1` (it's a push button), the line `while (digitalRead(sw1) == HIGH);` will make the code just sit there forever without continuing with the rest of the code until you press `sw1` again, which will be caught by the first `if` unless you release 'sw1' inhumanly fast.

So, once you have pressed and released `sw1`, the rest of the code with the next two `if`s will never run.

Comment: your last statement looks right, but somehow it can't figure out the problem.
If I held the sw1 down and press the sw2 then sw2 start working. Now only sw2 functions sw1 not working. The switching locks to sw2. but when I reset everything it goes back to sw1.

Comment: The while loops block the execution. Maybe it will work as you intended if you remove them and make the delays a bit shorter.

Comment: I use a DFmini player. It works well if the button is press and release. But in my case, the button will need to be held down. the problem with holding the button down is that the MP3 get played over and over. I want it to play only for once if the pin is high and or button is held down for a long time. If i remove the "while" then it will play over and over again. does not stop.

Comment: If you use a blocking delay, no button will respond during the delay time, and only repeat after the delay time. Or, debounce the buttons (you can look that up) and use a long debounce time, basically debouncing the push button and the human too.